How to solve this error : "object reference not set to an instance of an object"?
So IM working on a CRUD function where I add courses to the database. I'm using Cloudinary to upload the images to the cloud.
using LearnLink.Data;
using LearnLink.Models;
using LearnLink.ViewModel;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Data;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Linq;
using LearnLink.Interface;

namespace LearnLink.Controllers
{
    public class EducatorController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ICourseRepository _courseRepository;
        private readonly IPhotoService _photoService;

        public EducatorController(ICourseRepository courseRepository, IPhotoService photoService)
        {
            _courseRepository = courseRepository;
            _photoService = photoService;

        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            try
            {
                IEnumerable<Course> courses = await _courseRepository.GetAll();
                return View(courses);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Log the exception to the console
                Console.WriteLine($"Error occurred while getting courses: {ex}");
                // Return an error view or redirect to an error page
                return View("Error");
            }
        }
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create(CourseVM courseVM)
        {
            try
            {
                if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    if (_courseRepository == null)
                    {
                        throw new Exception("_courseRepository is null");
                    }

                    if (_photoService == null)
                    {
                        throw new Exception("_photoService is null");
                    }

                    if (courseVM.CourseImage == null)
                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError("", "CourseImage is required");
                        return View(courseVM);
                    }

                    var result = await _photoService.AddPhotoAsync(courseVM.CourseImage);
                    if (result == null)
                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Photo upload Failed");
                        return View(courseVM);
                    }

                    var course = new Course()
                    {
                        CourseName = courseVM.CourseName,
                        Description = courseVM.Description,
                        StartDate = courseVM.StartDate,
                        EndDate = courseVM.EndDate,
                        CourseImage = result.Url.ToString()
                    };

                    course.CreatedAt = DateTime.Now;
                    course.EducatorId = courseVM.EducatorId;

                    _courseRepository.Add(course);
                    _courseRepository.Save();

                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }

                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Photo upload Failed");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error occurred while creating course: {ex}");
                return View("Error");
            }

            return View(courseVM);
        }
    }
}


This is my controller.
And this is my CourseVM (View Model)
using LearnLink.Models;

namespace LearnLink.ViewModel
{
    public class CourseVM
    {
        public int CourseId { get; set; }
        public string CourseName { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }

        public IFormFile CourseImage { get; set; }

        public string EducatorId { get; set; }
        // Navigation property to represent the relationship between Course and User (Educator)
        public virtual ApplicationUser Educator { get; set; }

        // Navigation property to represent the relationship between Course and Enrollment
        public virtual ICollection<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; }
    }
}


Can Anyone help me figure out why I'm facing this error. I've checked line by line to my best ability yet the problem persists
